# Регистрация и авторизация пользователей

Tags: регистрация

Здравствуйте! У меня вопрос ко всем web-программистам. Четыре года назад я решил заняться Web-программированием. Мне 61 год, бывший летчик. Сайтостроение меня всегда интересовало. Благо появилось время и возможность заняться этим интересным делом. Самое необходимое для этого я изучил. Имею ввиду HTML, CSS и основы JavaScript, PHP, Ruby, Python, Node.js. Около сотни сайтов практически уже готовы для диплоида на сервере. Но вопрос в следующем. Самой сложной частью в кодировании является-регистрация и авторизация на сайте, которые требуют глубокого понимания всех требований, необходимых для валидации форм, необходимых действий для защиты своего сайта от SQL-инЪекций, взлома и т.д. Так вот, у меня возник вопрос,а чем плох сайт не имеющий Базы Данных, не имеющий формы регистрации пользователей. Этот сайт- не чат, не форум. Он носит информационно-позновательный характер и, в принципе, не нуждается в вышеперечисленных пунктах. И вообще, может ли такой сайт приносить хоть небольшой доход, как минимум, оправдывать себя и интернет?
Нужна ли вообще регистрация пользователей на таком сайте?
Прошу помощи разобраться в этих вопросах. Заранее всем благодарен. С уважением. Юрий Игоревич.

Answer (score 1):

1. Регистрация пользователей нужна только там, где она действительно нужна, как бы банально это не звучало. Она (как обязательный компонент) не нужна даже в сайтах-магазинах. Меня, например, безумно раздражает, когда заходишь в какой-то магазин за одной мелочью, а там требуют регистрацию. Сам админил в течении лет пяти самописный магазин, в котором можно было делать заказы и без регистрации - люди только рады были там покупать (регистрация всё равно была, но если человек хочет стать постоянным клиентом, накапливать скидку, ну и ради некоторых приятных мелочей типа автозаполнения формы доставки).
2. Наличие БД для создания сайта практически любой сложности совсем не обязательно. Например, [GetSimple CMS](http://get-simple.info/) и много подобных прекрасно обходятся без БД. Или немаленькие сайты, которые построены на wiki-движках. Правда, если совсем строго, какие-то подобия БД там всё равно есть - внутренние данные в любом случае где-то же хранить нужно.
3. А вот доходность сайта вообще никак не связана ни с одним из вышеперечисленных пунктов :-)

Comment: Спасибо Вам, что уделили мне внимание! Я в глубине так и предполагал. Меня тоже раздражает когда на сайте требуют обязательной регистрации. Часто я такой сайт оставляю без внимания. Ну, конечно, если это не сайт-магазин, в котором что-нибудь заказываешь. Еще раз спасибо за ответ. С уважением. Юрий Игоревич.

Answer (score 0):

> Около сотни сайтов практически уже готовы для диплоида на сервере.

И?

> Самой сложной частью в кодировании является-регистрация

Скорее самой простой...

> для защиты своего сайта от SQL-инЪекций

Они что, только при регистрации бывают?
И вообще, все нормальные языки давно содержат встроенные средства защиты от них.

> а чем плох сайт не имеющий Базы Данных, не имеющий формы регистрации пользователей

Ну и почему сайт не может быть с базой данных, но без регистрации пользователей?

А вообще, он плох тем, что он статический и ничего живого не содержит. Даже шаблонов и то не будет. Новости? На каждую заново копипастить страницу? Или всё-таки положить их в базу и вывести по одному шаблону?

> не имеющий формы регистрации пользователей

Не нужна регистрация, значит не нужна. Ну что тут ещё сказать можно?

> И вообще, может ли такой сайт приносить хоть небольшой доход, как минимум, оправдывать себя и интернет?

Это от содержимого зависит же.